# .resource file for WPF forms when loading assembly at run time?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Im trying to build a tool that loads an assembly as a byte[] at runtime (Assemly.Load(byte[]) 
It works  without any problems, as long as I dont open up a WPF form in the loaded assembly. 
Then my assembly resolve event fires up and asks for a file called [my project name].resources and I really dont understand how to produce this file and neither does google.

Is this somekind of wierd bug? Will I have to go back to using Winforms now that I just got aquinted with WPF?

Thanks!

/Erik

Comment: Does the WPF assembly use satelite assemblies?  If not, have you tried returning the loaded assembly (which contains the embedded resources already)?  See the Remarks section on this [MSDN ResourceManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) page.

Comment: Its just a plain wpf window inside a class library. I have basically just added it from the standard template and call it.
I have not added any resources manually (dont know if visual studio fiddles with something in the background). In the project settings under resources visual studio tells me that the project does not contain a default resource file.

Comment: Oh my god. It simple bug in my code!! I've been looking everywhere but in that place in my code...

Comment: I'm pleased you've found and fixed it.  I've added a formal answer anyway, as I think this is an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the ResolveEventHandler event is
>   raised for all assemblies, including resource assemblies.

Furthermore, the Microsoft [ResourceManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation sheds some light on where the .resources files can be found:

> The ResourceManager class retrieves resources from a binary .resources
>   file that is embedded in an assembly or from a standalone .resources
>   file. If an app has been localized and localized resources have been
>   deployed in satellite assemblies, it looks up culture-specific
>   resources, provides resource fallback when a localized resource does
>   not exist, and supports resource serialization.

So, depending on whether the assembly has been localised or not, you should return the assembly that contains the .resources file.  For non-localised assemblies this is (typically) the assembly itself; for localised assemblies this is the satelite assembly that contains the localised resources.

Although I've never tried it, I believe that the AssemblyResolve event may be raised several times for localised assemblies.  Each time you would need to return the satelite assembly that contained the matching localised .resources file, or NULL if the requested locale is not supported.